# cakephp id convention saveField issue

Tags: cakephp

I have a "production" table with field employee_id as a belongsTo relation to employees table.

The problem is my employees table uses field emp_appserial as primary key -as opposed to id field- (not every entry on employees table gets an id value, everyone gets auto increment emp_appserial)

I wonder if there is a way to use saveField using a field other than id to get to my record: (I mentioned I have records with no "id" value, only emp_appserial, which is pk)

```
    $this->loadModel('Employees');
    $this->Employees->id = $id;
    $this->Employees->saveField('emp_hrnote', 'text to be saved');
```

I'd like to use:

```
$this->Employees->emp_appserial = $id;
```

instead of

```
$this->Employees->id = $id;
```

I that doable?

Aside from that, it may not be too late to re-design my tables, but I already have a lot of production data :-(

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick (btw, models should be singular):

```
class Employees extends Model {
    public $primaryKey = 'emp_appserial';
}
```

If you don't set the `$primaryKey` attribute, it gets set to `id`: [Source](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model#l-682)

Once you set that `saveField()` will use that field for the condition: [Source](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model#l-1582)

Edit: Just to make it clear, you would still use `Model::$id` to set the primary key value. `Model::$id` holds the primary key **value**, `Model::$primaryKey` holds the primary key **field**

Comment: Thank you @tigrang; I was using `var $primaryKey = emp_appserial;` and did not notice it had apparently no effect; changed it to `public $primaryKey = 'emp_appserial';` as you noted and was able to saveField() provided using `$this->Employee->id = $id;`

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
    $this->Employee->updateAll(
            array('Employee.emp_hrnote' => "$thetxt"), 
            array('Employee.emp_appserial' => $id)
    );
```

As a workaround is just fine, however I wish I could solve my empty id issue... will post another issue with this on another post.

Comment: Yes it worked; this answer I posted right after posting the question to note that updateAll() also helped. Eventually was able to use saveField() using your answer.